# What's the easiest way to find an Ancient City?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In my Minecraft world, I am trying to find an Ancient City, a very rare and dangerous structure full of sculk, sculk sensors and (worst of all) sculk shriekers; a block that, upon being triggered three (3) times, will summon the Warden (a very horrifying mob that can kill you in with just five (5) hits if you have the best armor in the game).

I am trying to find one mainly for five (5) things:

- The Silence armor trim
- The Ward armor trim
- Notch apples
- Swift Sneak enchantment
- Disc 5 fragments (at least nine (9) of them)

I know that this will take me a very long time, which is why I am asking: ***What's the easiest way to find an Ancient City?***

***Note***: I do not want to use a seed mapper like Chunkbase, as I consider using that cheating.

Comment: Is it really possible to resist 5 Warden hits?

Comment: Yes. With netherite armor with protection IV enchanted on it, you will only take 2 hearts of damage (which is still a lot, tbh) if the Warden uses his melee attack on you. He does 5 hearts of damage, however, when he uses his super-sonic boom.

Comment: I'm curious - why not just use Chunkbase to look at where they are on your seed map?

Comment: @Catija I would think that you need to consider the fact that some people (including myself) consider seed mappers (like Chunkbase) cheating.

Comment: If that's something you want to avoid, that seems like an appropriate thing to mention in the question rather than waiting for someone to answer and say "just use Chunkbase" and then you say you don't want it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways that you can find an Ancient City!

You can:

- Mine and look under [these](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Mountains) mountain biomes (Ancient Cities will always have a *chance* of generating under these biomes).
- Look for caves with skulk (although this method can take a little longer).
- Mine and head down to a Y-level of negative 52, and just keep mining until you find a Deep Dark biome, then hope it has an Ancient City in it (I don't recommend this method, but if you are desperate enough, then you can try this method).

[Source](https://www.thegamer.com/minecraft-ancient-city-how-to-find-guide/#:%7E:text=All%20you%20can%20really%20do,that%20is%20close%20to%20you.)

Comment: [Non-fandom wiki link](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Mountains)

Comment: That article's claim that 75% of Ancient Cities spawn within 2000 blocks of your spawn location is false. They are distributed randomly throughout the world, as you can see with tools like this Ancient City finder: https://chunkbase.com/apps/ancient-city-finder. The claim seems to originate from this article, which has no source: https://minecraftminer.com/how-to-find-ancient-cities-in-minecraft-1-19-in-five-minutes